# Squid proxy server refuse connection for twitter

Tags: proxy, http-proxy, squid, polipo

I have installed Squid proxy on my Ubuntu 16 vps. This is my squid.conf:

```
auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid3/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid/passwords
auth_param basic realm proxy
acl authenticated proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access allow authenticated
http_port 3128
```

and this is my /etc/resolve.conf

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 1.1.1.1
```

on my other vps I'm using Polipo to proxy my project to this server. this is my Polipo config:

```
logSyslog = true
logFile = /var/log/polipo/polipo.log
parentProxy = "my proxy server address"
parentAuthCredentials = "my user name:my password"
```

I can access all other websites but when I try to connect to twitter.com I get this message:

```
curl -x 127.0.0.1:8123 https://twitter.com
curl: (56) Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT
```

Is there anything wrong here?

Comment: Did you find any solution?